# How can I create a constant Processing "Flow" using the TPL in C# 4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, queue, message-queue, task-parallel-library

I'm not sure if the following is possible but I'd like to Invoke a number of Actions, in Paralell, in a throttled manner, but keep the flow of processing continuous, without reverting back to using timers or loop/sleep cycles.

So far I've gotten it working that it loads a large batch of inputs from some source... and then processes them in paralell in a controlled way & loops around like below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true) //Simulate a Timer Elapsing...
    {
        IEnumerable<int> inputs = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};  
        //Simulate querying database queue tables for next batch of entries

        RunAllActions(inputs, 3); //Max 3 at a time.
    }
}

static void RunAllActions(IEnumerable<int> inputs, int maxConcurrency)
{
    var options = new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxConcurrency};

    Parallel.ForEach<int>(inputs, options, DoWork);
    //Blocks here until all inputs are processed.
    Console.WriteLine("Batch of Work Done!!!");
}

static void DoWork(int input)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Task {0}", input);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("Finishing Task {0}", input);
}
```

what I'd like to know is, Is there a construct in the TPL that I could use to keep it always running... so that I can replace the "Timer Elapsing" & "Database Polling" with a MessageQueue Receieved event.

The following is rough version of what I'd like to Achieve... there's otherways I can go about it, but I want to know is this sort of Pattern built into the TPL.

```
internal class Engine
{
    private MessageQueue mq;
    private Queue<int> myInternalApplicationQueue;

    public Engine()
    {
        //Message Queue to get new task inputs from
        mq = new MessageQueue();
        mq.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(mq_ReceiveCompleted);

        // internal Queue to put them in.
        myInternalApplicationQueue = new Queue<int>();
    }

    void mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //On MQ Receive, pop the input in a queue in my app
        int input = (int) e.Message.Body;

        myInternalApplicationQueue.Enqueue(input);
    }

    public void StartWorking()
    {
        //Once this gets called, it doesn't stop... it just keeps processing/watching that queue
        //processing the tasks as fast as it's allowed while the app is running.
        var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };
        Parallel.KeepWorkingOnQueue<int>(myInternalApplicationQueue, options, DoWork);
        //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <----- THIS GUY
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to handle this type of operation, which is effectively a producer/consumer scenario.

Basically, you'd setup a `BlockingCollection<T>` and use it as your "producer".  You would then have three (or any number) of *consumer* tasks (which are often setup as long running tasks) that process elements (by calling `blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()` in a standard foreach loop).

You then add items as needed to the collection, and they will continually be processed.  When you are completely done, you'd call [`BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx), which will cause the foreach loops to complete, and the entire thing stops.

As a side note - you typically do not want to use `Parallel.ForEach` on the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` from a `BlockingCollection<T>` - at least not unless you handle the partitioning yourself.  It's typically better to use multiple tasks and have each iterate sequentially.  The reason is that the default partitioning scheme in `Parallel.ForEach` will cause problems (it waits until a "chunk" of data is available, instead of immediately processing items, and the "chunks" get larger and larger over time).

Answer (score 2):

As Reed points out, BlockingCollection is a good "manual" way to go here. The downside is you have to also manage the consumers yourself.

Another approach that you might want to look into that takes a lot of the coordination work out of your hands for scenarios like this is to look into [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582). Specifically in a scenario like this you can just use an [`ActionBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and, when the message comes in from the queue you would just [`Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194836%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the new piece of data to the `ActionBlock<T>` and it will automatically process it using TPL worker threads under the covers. That would make your `Engine` class look a little something like this:

```
ActionBlock<int> myActionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(this.ProcessWorkItem);

void mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)      
{      
    int input = (int)e.Message.Body;

    // Post the data to the action block
    this.myActionBlock.Post(input);
}

private void ProcessWorkItem(int workItemData)
{
    // ActionBlock will hand each work item to this method for processing
}
```

Now, as far as controlling parallelism or capacity, you can easy control these specifics of the `ActionBlock<T>` by passing in an [`ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when constructing the `ActionBlock<T>`. So let's say I want to make sure that I never have a parallelism of more than four and block the producer from adding more than one hundred items to the queue. I would just do:

```
ActionBlock<int> myActionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(
                                     this.ProcessWorkItem, 
                                     new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                                     {
                                         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
                                         BoundedCapacity = 100
                                     });
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. That looks really interesting. Unfortunately I'm locked to .NET 4 or lower for now.

Comment: While TDF is baked into .NET 4.5, there is a separate download of TDF that just sits on top of .NET4 TPL. That's available from the TPL Dataflow main page I linked in my answer, but here's the direct download link (http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/6/F967673D-58D6-4E3F-8CA9-11769A0A63B1/TPLDataflow.msi) and here's the readme (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585583)

Comment: Cheers Drew. Yeah I've downloaded that on my own Test VM. but the piece of work I'm doing will be delivered to an existing Production environment and that's what I meant by being locked to .NET 4.0. thanks again.

Comment: @EoinCampbell Ah, I understand. Too bad since it makes life a heck of a lot easier. Sounds like you'll just have to go the "manual" route with BlockingCollection<T> then.

Comment: I've been dabbling with a some sample code today between a DB queue and background processor. I've just put a dumbed down version of it up on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/is-this-a-valid-producer-consumer-implementation-for-parallel-processing-in-th if you get a moment to take a look. Bit concerned over my usage of the BlockingCollection over long periods.

Comment: Actually TDF is still a separate download (from NuGet) even for .NET 4.5.1